# How do I keep reference in Django, when editing existing object?

Tags: django

So I have a field in my model which references another model. Like below. (simplified)

```
class Contents(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    body = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='imgs')
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)

class SavedContents(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    ref_content = models.ForeignKey(Contents, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='refcontent', null=True)
```

The problem is, the Foreign Key relationship, where the `Saved Contents` references `Contents`, is broken when making changes to an existing `Content` object. Below is my views.py

```
def update_content(request, content_id):
    content_to_update = Contents.objects.get(id = content_id)

    content_form = ContentsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if ans_form.is_valid():
            instance = content_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.updated_at = str(today)

            content_to_update.delete()
            instance.save()

        return redirect('/')
```

I know it's quite obvious that the referencing relationship is removed, since the original one is deleted. Is there any way that I can keep the foreign key relationship between that specific `Content` object and `Saved Content` object, no matter how many times a user makes changes to the content?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your question. Besides deletion, the foreign key relationship persists no matter how times a user changes the content. But you already indicated you understand the deletion aspect. Can you please try to rephrase your question so that I can help you better?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So as written in the question, the existing object is deleted in order to save the new(editted) object, right? So because of the deletion, the foreign key relationship is deleted as well`on_delete=CASCADE`). Am I right?

Comment: But I need the foreign key relationship to be remained, no matter how many changes there are. For example, let's say I have a `Saved Content` object that references a `Content` object which like this: `{id:1, body:'foo', created_at:2021-09-05}`. Now if I make change to the `Content` object, into `{id:2, body:'bar', created_at:2021-09-05}`, the foreign key relationship(referencing `id:1`) is deleted, right? But I need that `Saved Content` object to maintain the relationship. Has this clarified the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don' t need to delete the instance when you update it (Django simply updates the database row, so delete the instance has no sense):

```py
from django.utils import timezone

def update_content(request, content_id):
    content_to_update = Contents.objects.get(id=content_id)

    content_form = ContentsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if content_form.is_valid():
            instance = content_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.updated_at = timezone.now().date()
            instance.save()
        return redirect('/')
```